# DynamicLinkParameters path flutter and firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-dynamic-links

i trying to implement firebase dynamic links in my app

```
    FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink(onSuccess: (PendingDynamicLinkData dynamicLink) async {
   if (deepLink.queryParameters.containsKey('id')){
     String shareid = deepLink.queryParameters['id'];
         Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
   return ShareDetalisPages(
    
     shareid: shareid,
    );

  }
  )
  );
   }
```

this example above for links like example.com/?id=1
my api exmaple like that  path
example.com/product/id
example.com/product/123
how to manage api path like that